# Linux shell, get all the matches from a file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have a file like the following format:

```
line one  
line two <% word1  %> text <% word2 %>  
line three <%word3%>
```

I want to use linux shell tools like awk, sed etc to get all the words quoted in <% %>
result should be like

```
word1  
word2  
word3
```

Thanks for help.

I forgot to mention: I am in embedded environment. grep has no -P option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '<% *| *%>' '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' file
word1
word2
word3
```

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk so we can RS to multiple characters:

```
$ gawk -v RS='<% *| *%>' '!(NR%2)' file
word1
word2
word3
```

With any modern awk:

```
$ awk -F'<% *| *%>' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' file
word1
word2
word3
```

Comment: That's quite beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with grep:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=<%).+?(?=%>)' file
 word1  
 word2 
word3
```

Comment: Thanks! Forget to mention, I am in embedded environment.  grep has no -P option

Answer (score 2):

This works for your sample:

```
sed -ne 's/%>/&\n/p' | sed -ne 's/.*<%\s*\(.*\)\s*%>.*/\1/p' < sample.txt
```

The first `sed` just puts a line break after every closing `%>`, as preparation.

The next `sed` extracts the relevant part within `<% ... %>` without leading and trailing whitespaces.

In both commands, the `-n` flag combined with `s///p` are to limit the data going through the pipe to the matching (relevant) lines only.

Comment: Just be aware there's 2 non-portable sed constructs in the above: a) use of `\n` as a newline (backslash followed by a literal carriage return is portable) and b) use of `\s` to represent a space character (`[[:blank:]]` is POSIX, but in this case a literal blank char is probably adequate). I'm surprised your sed works with those when your grep doesn't support `-P`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<%\s*/!d;s//\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\s*%>/\n/;P;D' file
```